# How to create bubble charts using NVD3

Tags: arrays, d3.js, nvd3.js, circle-pack

How to create a bubble chart as in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063269/:

[image]

...but using NVD3?

The NVD3 site only has reference to Scatter plot http://nvd3.org/ghpages/scatter.html

Comment: Unfortunately NVD3 does not have the bubble chart feature. You might have to use M.Bostocks' example. Or try writing your own.

Comment: You can create scatterplots with different sized circles in NVD3, and then just use index numbers to position them into rows and columns.  But the packed circle layout isn't one of their layouts.  NVD3 is mostly focused on creating  online versions of standard graph structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This custom nvd3 bubble chart implementation might help anyone who wants to figure out how to do it: https://github.com/enplore/nvd3-charts.